# PHP Imagick transparency issue with PNG

Tags: php, rotation, imagemagick, png, imagick

I am using imagemagick 6.8.4-6 and i'm having an issue with setting the PNG on rotate to have a transparent background. My code is below and i am using imagick through php

```
$base = new Imagick("images/Champs-43.png"); 
$layer = new Imagick("images/coporate1.png");
$base->setFormat("png32");
$layer->setFormat("png32");
$layer->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel("none"), 45);

$base->compositeImage($layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 20, 20);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $base;
```

the above gives a black background to the area rotated. i have tried "none", "transparent", "#00000000", and "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)" and none of them seem to work.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the ImagickPixel.

You can try these:

```
$layer->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('#FFFFFF'), 45);
```

or

```
$layer->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel('#00000000', 45);
```

Comment: i've already tried it and it doesn't work. Thanks for your input though

Comment: If it not working, Try this: Rotate image and than place the rotated image on a transparent background and fuse it.

Comment: thankyou again for your comment. I have tried a transparent background from scratch with a png image. as soon as i fuse them and rotate it has a black background regardless of if i fuse and rotate the transparent and then merge or merge then rotate.

Comment: You need to first rotate it and than place it on transparent background(the background should have dimensions equal to the rotated image, which you will need to take care off) and then fuse. It had worked for me. Next thing, i have now started using GMagick, which is fast and simple. Its easy in Gmagick to do this :).